# Include XSD in Jar with Maven?

Tags: maven-2, xsd, pom.xml

We have an XSD file along with some java src files.  How can we instruct Maven to include the XSD in the jar file output?  Currently it appears to ignore the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the XSD file under `src/main/resources` folder. This should be enough. By default all files under this directory are copied to `target/classes` directory and from there are picked up by `maven-jar-plugin` by default.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative, configure `project/build/resources` in your pom. See [this reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources).